# Call Oracle Function and set it to entity

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Please forgive me if this issue already exist. Here is my scenario:

```
class EntityA {
  private EntityB entityB;
  ...
}
```

I need to call **functionA(entityB.value)** (this is oracle function)

The way I resolved it is I will get list of EntityA, then loops it

```
for(EntityA entityA : entityAList){
  // then I will call oracle function here
  callOracleFunction(entityA.entityB.value)
}
```

It resolved the problem, but the query will be called multiple times.
How can I query it in one go ?
Like this query

```
SELECT a.name,
functionA(b.value) AS "Result"
FROM EntityA a
LEFT JOIN EntityB b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Quick dumb solution
1 Create new oracle function with your "SELECT a.name,
functionA(b.value)" inside it
2 Call new function once

Comment: VasilyKomarov I already have oracle function, just want to use it. I tried @Formula but it still calling function for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `@Formula` is better way for this situation, at least it's better than my current solution. Thanks